# AndroidJUnit4 not found after Gradle update on AndroidStudio 3.1.1

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

I had been running my unit test so far without any problems until we decide to update the gradle version from 3.1 to 4.6 and the gradle plugging from 2.3.3 to 3.5. After this update the project run without any problem and even the unit tests runs fine but not the ones that need to import AndroidJUnit4 because it can't resolve the dependence any more.

On the build.gradle we are importing:

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`androidTestImplementation` and the runner are used for UI tests. You seem to not be explicitly importing JUnit:

`testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"`